# Json is undefined in cURL

Tags: json, curl, jira-rest-java-api

I need to automate the issues insertion in Jira, so I need to use a REST API, I run the curl from the command line, here is my command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl.exe -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data { "fields": {"project": { "key"="ZZZ-180" }, "summary": "REST TESTING" , "description": "Creation of a testing issue" , "issuretype" { "name": "Bug"}}} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://ABCD.com:XXXX/rest/api/2/issue/
```

and here is what I receive:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: fields
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 10
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: key=
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ZZZ-180
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: summary
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: REST TESTING
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: description
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Creating of a testing issue
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: issuretype
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 4
```

Can anyone help me let the cURL define the JSON code written in data?

Comment: You have to quote the parameter, otherwise curl will use `{` as data and interpret the other parts as parameters (unknown)...

Comment: I tried but still the same error

Comment: also remove the white spaces `{"fields":{`

Comment: @Blundell. My case was the spaces on the string. So unusual to my understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to quote the string, but simplest way is putting JSON data in a file and asking cURL to read from it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl.exe -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data @data_to_send.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://ABCD.com:XXXX/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Note the `@` before file name.

Comment: I tried it but still JSON code is totally undefined.. How to identify JSON in curl,,, I never used JSON before so Sorry for my lack of knowledge abt how to install JSON to be used in cURL

Comment: You do not have to install JSON, JSON is a file format ;) cURL will simply transfer the content of `data_to_send.json`: put the JSON string in it and navigate to the folder or give full path (like `--data C:\path\to\data_to_send.json`).

Comment: Thanks so much,,, The problem now is in the authorization to the REST API! thanks anyways

Comment: I was trying to write this command in perl script to be passed to the command prompt... I used backtracks ``  but it was always giving an error for the @ notation before the JSON file path... any suggestions?

Comment: how do you quote the string?

Comment: By enclosing it between `"` and adding a backslash `\ ` before all `"` contained in the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your --data should look something like:

```
"{ \"fields\": {\"project\": { \"key\"=\"ZZZ-180\" }, \"summary\": \"REST TESTING\" , \"description\": \"Creation of a testing issue\" , \"issuretype\" { \"name\": \"Bug\"}}}"
```